# Изменение директории

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Есть `.htaccess` файл, который лежит в корне сайта:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
DefaultLanguage ru
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value default_charset "utf-8"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/index.php [L]
```

Данный скрипт перенаправляет на `/www/index.php`, если по url нету файла. Например, если у нас в корне есть файла `test.php` и мы введём `domain.ru/test.php`, то откроется это файл, а если мы введём `domain.ru/file.php`, но такого файла в корне не будет, у нас откроется `/www/index.php`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при запросе к файлу он сам добавлял `/www` к путю.

Сейчас, чтобы получить файл `/www/test.txt`, нужно писать `domain.ru/www/test.txt`.
А нужно, чтобы просто `domain.ru/test.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/index.php [L]
```

Указывает на то, что берем любую строку приходящую и отправляем ее на /www/index.php. Соответсвенно, нам надо сделать так, чтобы эта строка продублировалась вправо.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

Ура - все поломалось, так как сейчас мы тут и /www/ тоже редиректим в /www/www/....
Что делать? А вот что:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /www/$1 [L]
```

Вот и все.

Comment: Работает, но есть проблема. Если нам нужно открыть не в корне папки www файла, а например, /www/test/test.txt, то он открывает /www/index.php вместо /www/test/test.txt

Comment: по момему суть в том что вы написали RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
т.е. вы проверили только файлы, если надо и папки так определите это
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.txt www/test.txt [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Мне нужно не для одного определёного файла, а для всех, которые находятся в /www